# Distribution provisioning profile issue

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I am currently fixing bugs for a client who had the iPhone app made by someone else.

I think i have to use the clients distribution certificate to upload the binary of update..

I downloaded the distribution certificate but Xcode is complaining valid sign identity not found.

I know it is an issue with the keychain .. i don't have accces to the keys of the original developer..

how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Invalidate the certificate
2. Create a new one
3. Create a new distribution profile using the new certificate.
4. Install that profile in XCode
5. ???
6. Profit :)

Comment: i though of invalidating .. but it had all app details in it . like profile name and app id.. so if i invalidate and make a new one?? do i have to use the same things and then will i be able to upload the version update binary through iTunes connect?

Comment: It is only the certificate you are invalidating. You'll also need to regenerate the provisioning profile. As long as you don't change the bundle identifier you can still upload to iTunes connect.

Answer (score 0):

If use certificate from another person then you are in need of private key. **Without private key, you will be unable to sign binaries in Xcode and test your application on any Apple device.** Try to request a `.p12` file from original developer for this certificate or create new one yourself.

Comment: i don't think keys will be available now .. i though of creating new certificate .. but the original one had all app details in it . like profile name and app id.. so if i invalidate and make a new one?? do i have to use the same things and then will i be able to upload the version update binary through iTunes connect?

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete any certificates you might have from the provisioning portal
2. Create a new Certificate Signing Request on your mac
3. Upload that request to the Provisioning portal to generate a new certificate
4. Associate your existing provisioning profile to the newly generated Certificate
5. Add the new provisioning profile to XCode
6. Compile your app :-) Done.

This will not delete any app details. This is just creating a new certificate. You will still be able to use all your old details. So dont worry.